# .htaccess problem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect what's in link after `localhost/myScript/` to `localhost/myScript/test.php?var=$1`.

So.. something like

```
localhost/myScript/this/is/just/a/test/
```

(with or without the last slash) would redirect to

```
localhost/myScript/test.php?var=this/is/just/a/test
```

This is what I've got, but it's not good enough.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test.php?var=$1
```

I've tried using

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ test.php?var=$1
```

But, I get `$_GET['var'] = 'test.php'`.

Comment: Which directory is the .htaccess file in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 main approaches:

**1.** Two separate rules to deal with URL with and without trailing slash. It will only rewrite requests to non-existing files/folder thus preventing rewrite loop you are having:

```
# work with URL that ends with slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ test.php?var=$1 [L]

# work with the rest of URLs (that ends with no slash)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test.php?var=$1 [L]
```

**2.** Have separate rule to ignore existing files (to not to rewrite already rewritten URLs) and then use 1 line rewrite rule for URL with and without trailing slash:

```
# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# rewrite URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/$ test.php?var=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ test.php?var=$1 [L]
```

I would prefer #2.

Answer (score 1):

this is better one

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ test.php?var=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've edited this to fit my requirements: 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ test.php?var=$1 [L]
Thank you!

Comment: I found an error. If I try to request an image it will pass the request to test.php.

Comment: @D1Error you have forgot to include my first line. First line ensures filename do not contain .php

Comment: This is how my .htacceess looks: 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ test.php?var=$1 [L]
If I don't include the condition the var will automatically get the test.php value.

Comment: @D1Error working here http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/bc6fb -> rewriting to g/bc6fb.php

Comment: You don't understand my question.

Comment: @D1Error I do, you told images aren't working for you. I proved they do for me http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/bc6fb/3

Comment: Ok. I'll try to explain again. I want localhost/myScript/this/is/a/test to be redirected to localhost/myScript/test.php?var=this/is/a/test, where this/is/a/test can be replaced with anything else. If the link is an image, css or any kind of resource, I don't want the rule to apply.

Comment: @D1Error that's exactly what my lines do

Comment: Try downloading http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8087080/webserver.rar and access http://localhost/test.jpg it will display Array
(
    [var] => test.jpg
)

Comment: Whoops. change second line to 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php
 and it will work

Comment: Now, localhost/myScript/this/is/a/test won't be redirected to localhost/myScript/test.php?var=this/is/a/test.